# React native expo file upload error: Network request failed issue . using form data and fetch

Tags: reactjs, expo, native

```
async function uploadImages() {
    const token = "eyJhHGFvg";
    const workforceId = "ca2f4c1f-606f-44e7-a633-1f914d29e3d1";
    console.log(selectedImage);
    const fileType = 1;
    const url = 'http://www.kushal.com/kk.api/workforce/fileupload';

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', {
        uri: selectedImage,
        type: fileType,
        name: 'image.jpg'
    });
    formData.append('WorkforceId', workforceId);
    formData.append('fileType', fileType);

    console.log(formData);

    const headers = {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    };

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers,
        body: formData
    };
    console.log(options);

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, options);
        console.log(response);
        if (response.ok) {
            Alert.alert('Success', 'File uploaded successfully.');
        } else {
            Alert.alert('Error', 'Failed to upload file.');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Failed to upload file.');
    }
}
```

the above image upload function is giving network request failed , Please check and tell what is the error

I am attaching the log of form data and response
[image]

please try to help as soon as possible i am stuck on this since one week .
..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

......................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Can you make a dummy example in jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: It is a big project , can you share your email for communication , I can send you github repo link